# json payload arguments and PUT method directly with the dispatch

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-framework3, dispatch

The third parameter is an array in the dispatch method, so **how can I pass the JSON payload in PUT request**?

Json paload - `{"website":"test"}`

Example,

`$this->dispatch(
        'testUrl',
        'PUT',
        [json_encode($param)]
   );`

If I pass like that then facing an error like wrong input.

Answer (score 0):

We need to pass data in request setContent function instead of the dispatch argument.

```
/** @var Request $request */
$request = $this->getRequest();
$request->setHeaders($headers);
$request->setMethod('PUT');
$request->setContent(json_encode($payload)); //{"website":"test"}

$this->dispatch(
   'testUrl'
);
```